# Proving that $1+x \in R^{\ast}$ for all $ x \in \ker f.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $R$ is a non-trivial ring with $1$, and $f : R \to R, f(x) = x^2$ is a ring homomorphism, then I want to prove that  $1+x \in R^{\ast}$ for all $ x \in \ker f.$ First, I have shown that $R$ has characteristic $2$:

$$ f(1) = 1^2 = 1$$
$$ f(x+y) = (x+y)^2 = x^2+2xy +y^2 = f(x) + f(y) = x^2 + y^2$$
$$f(xy)= x^2y^2=f(x)f(y).$$

Because $$x^2+2xy +y^2 = x^2 + y^2, $$
$$2xy=0 \ \forall \ x,y \in R \ \text{and} \ 2xy =0 \in R.$$

So,
$$f(2xy)=(2xy)^2=2^2x^2y^2=f(0)=0.$$

Finally,
$$ \ker(f) = \{ 2xy \in R \ | \ x,y \in R \} = \{2xy \in R \ | \ xy \in R \},$$
and $\ker(f) = (2).$

However, I am at a complete loss how to proceed from here in proving that $1+x \in R^{\ast}$ for all $ x \in \ker f.$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $(1+x)(1-x)=1-x^2=1$.

Comment: Have you tried computing $(1+x)^2$, knowing that $R$ has characteristic 2, and keeping in mind the fact that $x^2=0$?

Comment: Ah I think i see, if $x \in \ker(f)$ then $f(x)=x^2=0.$ From $(1+x)(1-x)=1-x^2=1$ it follows that $x \in \ker(f)$ has an element $1+x \in R$ which has multiplicative inverse $1-x.$ Therefore $(1+x)^2 =1+2x+x^2=1$, because $f(2x)=f(x)=0.$

Comment: @Ruben: As regards your comment, a corrected version of your last line would be $(1+x)^2=1+2x + x^2 = 1$ because $2x=0$ and $x^2=0$. Also, you don't need both $(1+x)(1-x)=1$ _and_ $(1+x)^2=1$. In essence, they're the same statement since $1-x=1+x$, and in any case, either will suffice.

Comment: @Ruben: Note also: You didn't prove that $\ker(f)=(2)$. What you proved is that $2xy=0$, for all $x,y$, hence in particular, using $x=y=1$, you get that $2=0$ (which is all you need to apply the hint in the above comment by C.W). Note: If it were actually the case that $\ker(f)=(2)$, that would mean $\ker(f)=(0)$. Note also: As the hint by David C. Ullrich and the answer by mweiss makes clear, to prove $x\in\ker(f)$ implies $1+x$ is a unit, you don't even need to show $2=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually need to prove that $R$ has characteristic 2.  The fact that $1 + r$ is invertible for $r\in \ker(f)$ comes directly from the calculation
$$(1+r)(1-r) = 1 - r^2 = 1 - f(r) = 1$$
This not only shows that $1+r$ has an inverse, but also gives you an explicit formula for the inverse.